# How do i get id from href if page routing?

Tags: php

I am trying to get the id from the link below. It works to skip the page routing but i need to use the page routing and that breaks the `$_GET['id']`. Is there some way for me to get this working with page routing or should i look at another solution?

on **HOME.PHP** i write this:

```
<h1 class="post-title"><a href="viewlink?id=<?php echo $row['postID'] ?>"><?php echo $row['postTitle'] ?></a></h1>
```

I am page routing all my pages from the root which seems to not give me the

**viewlink.php**

```
echo $_GET['id'];
```

This is how i page route

```
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
   $page = $_GET['page'];
       if ($page == "index") {
            require_once "frontend/pages/index.php";
 } elseif ($page == "viewlink") {
            require_once "frontend/pages/viewlink.php";
        }
    }
```

Comment: <a href="viewlink **.php** ? without the spaces of course

Comment: @JorgeCampos Did you miss the page routing part? " viewlink" is = frontend/pages/viewlink.php

Comment: No I didn't, as of now your href only has a string on it not a php variable. maybe you are trying `<a href="<?php echo $viewlink?>?....`

Comment: Your code makes little sense, that's why the close votes as Unclear what are you asking.  Your home.php has an href tag that points to nowhere unless you have redirect rules on your server and it is also not clear where the "page route" code is or what is supposed to do

Comment: @JorgeCampos Sorry forgot to mention im also rewriting the url with .htaccess so im removing a lot. But the problem is not that im not getting to the page viewlink.php i am, it's just that the id doesn't pass with it.

Comment: i think this can be achieve through your htaccess without your page rout code snippet. you can add a rule `RewriteRule ^viewlink viewlink.php [L]` and then in `viewlink.php` you can get id with `$_GET['id']`

Answer (score 0):

You don't show how you route so it's impossible to tell how you get to your base `page` key. If you do some standard method of rewrite, you are probably left with a `$_SERVER` array something similar to this. Any one of those values could be what you need to extract the `id` like `QUERY_STRING`, `REQUEST_URI`, or `REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING`...etc.:

```
Array
(
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/http/htdocs/iwantcreative
    [DOMAIN_NAME] => www.example.com
    [DOMAIN_NAME_REAL] => example.com
    [DOMAIN_PATH] => /var/http/htdocs/iwantcreative
    [DOMAIN_USER] => 2948313.3268049
    [FCGI_ROLE] => RESPONDER
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-us
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => close
    [HTTP_COOKIE] => PHPSESSID=123123123123123123aaaaabbbbccccc
    [HTTP_DNT] => 1
    [HTTP_HOST] => www.example.com
    [HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS] => 1
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS 7_6_2) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0.2 Safari/604.4.7
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] => 123.123.123.1
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO] => http
    [HTTP_X_REAL_IP] => 111.111.111.1
    [PHP_SELF] => /index.php
    [PHP_WRAPPER_VERSION] => 560
    [PKEY] => 123123123.321321321
    [QUERY_STRING] => viewlink/&id=100
    [RAILS_URI] => INVAL
    [REDIRECT_DOMAIN_NAME] => www.example.com
    [REDIRECT_DOMAIN_NAME_REAL] => example.com
    [REDIRECT_DOMAIN_PATH] => /var/http/htdocs/myrootfolder
    [REDIRECT_PKEY] => 123123123.321321321
    [REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING] => viewlink/&id=100
    [REDIRECT_RAILS_URI] => INVAL
    [REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URI] => http://www.example.com/viewlink/
    [REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URL] => /viewlink/
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [REDIRECT_URL] => /viewlink/
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 111.111.111.1
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 57480
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1515127759
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1515127759.7582
    [REQUEST_URI] => /viewlink/&id=100
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/http/htdocs/myrootfolder/index.php
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
    [SCRIPT_URI] => http://www.example.com/viewlink/
    [SCRIPT_URL] => /viewlink/
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 123.123.123.1
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => [no address given]
    [SERVER_NAME] => www.example.com
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.0
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => 
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache
    [argc] => 1
    [argv] => Array
        (
            [0] => viewlink/&id=100
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you also have some kind of url rewriting set up, that you didn't mention. Normally this link: `<a href="viewlink?...` would probably lead to a 404 because it's missing the .php extension.

How do you get from `<a href="viewlink?...` to the routing part? I guess you have a mistake in that - check RewriteRule (apache), they need to have `[QSA]` - "query string append" at the end of the line. Query string is anything after "?" in the url, so `?id=` in your case